# Why can't I see my past questions?

Tags: support, user-accounts

A couple weeks ago when I logged into this "ask ubuntu" website, all my past questions and activity (and points/score) vanished.

I have enjoyed "ask ubuntu" for a year or so, and don't understand what happened, or how to fix this.  My user/login name is still the same as always (honestann).  Does anyone know what is this problem?

I have also participated in "stack overflow" too (with the same user/login name), in case that fact might have something to do with this problem.

Also, when I logged in today, even my recent activity in the past couple weeks has vanished... again.

Comment: Your other id still exist, Probably you logged in using another account

Comment: How can I do that?  When I visit the page, the website recognizes me offers to log me in (and I click okay).  Assuming I have another account, can it have the same username?  Can two totally different people have the same username?  Finally, how do I find my old accounts?

Comment: ^Your accounts merged

Answer (score 8):

#### unregistered vs registered

Your original account was unregistered - this depends upon your Web-Browser remembering your login credentials via a cookie.

If the cookie is lost, then your login credentials is also lost.

You now have registered your account thus you no longer have to depend upon your browser.

Your old account and new account have been merged.

Just to say - welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

Comment: Well, then where are all my old questions?  The account I had for a year or two had about a dozen questions.  Now I see I have a lot more points but no past activity/questions.  It is as if my points are restored, but not my past activity.  I'm confused!

Comment: 15 questions in total ... http://askubuntu.com/users/123307/honestann

Comment: Thanks, they're back now.